# Can't find advanced-cache.php and db.php in FTP - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, ftp, w3-total-cache

The 0.9.5 w3-total-cache plugin update for some reason caused my website to time out very often. So I decided to remove it. When I tried to remove it via the dashboard, the website white screened - can't do anything!

So I removed the plugin via FTP, now Wordpress is saying this...

> W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /var/www/vhosts/futureldn.co/httpdocs/wp-content/advanced-cache.php.W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /var/www/vhosts/futureldn.co/httpdocs/wp-content/db.php.W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /var/www/vhosts/futureldn.co/httpdocs/wp-content/object-cache.php.

But I just can't find the 3 files to remove in FTP. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'd like to try WP Super Cache but I should remove these files first...

Thank you!

Comment: Is futureldn.co your domain? if so, those pages are still in the server (see: futureldn.co/wp-content/db.php). What is your structure like? Maybe the files are symlinked?

Comment: it is... in wp-content there are these folders:

cache, languages, plugins, themes, upgrade and uploads. In the cache folder there is another called db (maybe this is db.php?) but what about the other 2? And why would Wordpress not have 'cache' in the path it has told me?

Comment: I do not have much experience with backend so please forgive my lack of knowledge...

Comment: The file path shows that those 3 files sit inside the "wp-content" folder, not within the "cache" folder. Check again (or post) the file structure of "wp-content" if you're still having trouble

Comment: Ok, but I only have those 6 folders I mentioned, there are no individual files in there at all... Is there any chance some could be hidden?

Comment: Maybe, if there's no individual files that's a bit freaky. Which FTP client do you use? [If you use Filezilla, here's how you can show hidden files](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Web-Hosting/Files-and-FTP/accessing-hidden-files-via-ftp-filezilla-4162/).  You should atleast have an index page in that folder.

Comment: I am using Filezilla, and the 'Force show hidden files' didn't reveal anything... I just did a file search and Filezilla says the file (advanced-cache.php) doesn't exist. I am rather confused!

Comment: index.php is in wp-admin/user folder!

Comment: Expected, since /wp-admin is how you access your admin control panel. Do you have access to SSH on the server? if so you can try running `find /var/www/vhosts/futureldn.co/httpdocs/wp-content/ -name "dp.php"` to locate the file. Or maybe ask your host to locate these files. they should be (and visible) in the wp-content folder.

Comment: thank you, I did that search but nothing came up, apparently the files do not exist... I'm going to contact my Hosting company. Thank you for your help! Thought I was going mad! :)